# How may I Obtain a RHEL/CentOS in OVA Format?

Tags: virtual-machine, vmware, virtualization

My company has an internal cloud that provisions VMs either in an OpenStack (KVM) or a VMware (ESX) hypervisor.  It already provides RHEL 6.4 on the KVM, but I've used up the max number of VMs from that hypervisor and need to start using the ESX one. However, the ESX does not have any RHEL templates and takes uploads of virtual machines in "OVA" format.

"OFV" can be converted into "OVA", so I could use that as well. Yet I can't find a download of either of these files.

Is there any link to a direct download? If not, how may I create an OVF/OVA of a RHEL 6.4 or CentOS 6.4?

Answer (score 2):

You might have some luck here:
http://virtualboxes.org/images/centos/

Otherwise you can probably obtain a virtualization solution that supports OVF/OVA exporting, install from media and export your own OVF/OVAs.  Easiest one is VirtualBox from Oracle - virtualbox.org

Pertinent install media for Centos cen be downloaded from [CentOS Mirrors](http://www.centos.org/modules/tinycontent/index.php?id=13).  If you already have RedHat, those ISOs can be used as well.